# SyntaxError: invalid syntax on Jupyter Notebook in Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create a `labelmap` in Jupyter Notebook on a Linux machine but I'm getting this syntax error

Code:

```
labels = [{'name':'licence', 'id':1}
with open(files['LABELMAP'], 'w') as f:
    for label in labels:
        f.write('item { \n')
        f.write('\tname:\'{}\'\n'.format(label['name']))
        f.write('\tid:{}\n'.format(label['id']))
        f.write('}\n')
```

Error:

```
 File "/tmp/ipykernel_844/1834800190.py", line 3
   with open(files['LABELMAP'], 'w') as f:
   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Your program is in the programming language Python. You want Python programmers to look at your code, so you must add the [python] tag. All the other tags are rather irrelevant, this is not a problem in deep learning or computer vision, it is not a problem with Linux, it is a Python syntax error. Using the right tags to get the right eyeballs on your question is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error probably came from the first line. You forgot to close the labels bracket:

```
labels = [{'name':'licence', 'id':1}]
```

Errors like this are usually pointed in the next line, where the compiler realises there is a syntax error in the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. it is solved now